# Ng-Checked with ng-repeat without using for loop in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

Can anyone help to figure out ng-checked

```
$scope.ABC=[{ID:23,NAME:zz},{ID:65,NAME:tt},{},{}]

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="AllChecked" /></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in ABC">
        <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
        <td>{{x.NAME}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.selection"  ng-checked="AllChecked" required /></td>    
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
Output i want:- 
[{ID:x.23,Select:true},{ID:x.65,Select:true},{ID:x.ID,Select:true}]
```

This work if i use for loop. But i do not want to use loop. Is there any other way any one can hep.I tried with ng-change, ng-click but still didn't work.

Comment: Is your issue with the "select all" functionality or with the ng-repeat not working as you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your issue lies with the select all functionality not working or the ng-repeat over your array.

And i guess you want your object to become like this:

`[{ID:23,NAME:zz, checked: true},{ID:65,NAME:tt, checked: true},etc]`

If thats the case, check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/8egEhVWOvgfLTTlUfSnL?p=preview) plunker for the solution.